# Why does ConfigParserProperty only work for Widgets created with kv in examples below

Tags: properties, kivy

The following code works as I expect. When I enter a Number in TextInput and press RETURN, the number is shown in all 3 Labels.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ConfigParserProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<MyBoxLayout>
    TextInput:
        text: "insert Number <RETURN>"
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.numberprop=self.text
    Label:
        text: str(root.numberprop)
    Label:
        text: str(root.numberprop)
    Label:
        text: str(root.numberprop)
""")

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    numberprop= ConfigParserProperty(3, 'one', 'two', 'app',
                                  val_type=int, errorvalue=41)

class TstApp(App):
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('one', {'two' : '70'})

    def build(self, **kw):
        return MyBoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TstApp().run()
```

The following code does not work as I expect. When I enter a number in Textinput and press RETURN, only the last Label shows the number.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ConfigParserProperty

def MyConfigParserProperty():
    return ConfigParserProperty(3, 'one', 'two', 'app',
                                  val_type=int, errorvalue=41)

Builder.load_string("""
<MyBoxLayout>
    TextInput:
        text: "insert Number <RETURN>"
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.numberprop=self.text

<MyLabel>
    text: str(root.numberprop)
""")

class MyLabel(Label):
    numberprop=MyConfigParserProperty()

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    numberprop=MyConfigParserProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MyBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
        for i in range(3):
            self.add_widget(MyLabel())

class TstApp(App):
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('one', {'two' : '70'})

    def build(self, **kw):
        return MyBoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TstApp().run()
```

I need a way to create Labels dynamically. How can I do it ?

Comment: `root` is local to the kv rule; in the MyLabel rule, it refers to MyLabel, not to the parent MyBoxLayout.

Comment: yes, but MyLabel and MyBoxLayout have both the same numberprop, so it should not matter. And it also works for the last MyLabel. Why not for the first two MyLabels ?

Comment: Oh, it's something to do with returning a ConfigParserProperty from a function being a bad idea. I'm not sure exactly why this leads to problems though. You can apparently solve it by not doing that and declaring it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ConfigParserProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<MyBoxLayout>
    TextInput:
        text: "insert Number <RETURN>"
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: app.numberprop=self.text

<MyLabel>
    text: str(app.numberprop)
""")

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MyBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
        for i in range(3):
            self.add_widget(MyLabel())

class TstApp(App):
    numberprop=ConfigParserProperty(3, 'one', 'two', 'app',
                                  val_type=int, errorvalue=41)

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('one', {'two' : '70'})

    def build(self, **kw):
        return MyBoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TstApp().run()
```